# I want to identify iphone versions in my project in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

hi iam using the following code in my project

```
#define isiPhone6 ( [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667)?TRUE:FALSE
#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE

UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = nil;

if (isiPhone5)
    {  
            mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainIphone5" bundle:nil];;

        // this is iphone 4 inch
    }

  else  if (isiPhone6)
    {

        mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainIphone6" bundle:nil];;

        // this is iphone 4 inch
    }


  else
    {
        mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        //Iphone  3.5 inch
    }


self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

but the loop is not entering in to the isiphone6 and simulator taking the iphone5 storyboards.
 whats the problem can anyone help me please.......

Comment: Do you have an iphone6/iphone6plus launchimage? If you don't the scaling will be applied and the app will think it's on the lower screen size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check iOS Simulator type and version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670898/check-ios-simulator-type-and-version)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [SDVersion](https://github.com/sebyddd/SDVersion) ( https://github.com/sebyddd/SDVersion) library.

It does exactly what you need, and much more. You can also check whether its an iPad, iPhone 5C, 5S, 6, 6Plus, Mac, etc. It's great. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

See this Class

https://github.com/froztbytes/UIDeviceHardware

Or Create this class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIDeviceHardware : NSObject
 + (NSString *) platform;
 + (NSString *) platformString;
@end



#import "UIDeviceHardware.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

@implementation UIDeviceHardware

+ (NSString *) platform{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
    free(machine);
    return platform;
}

+ (NSString *) platformString{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone 4 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5C";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5C";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (CDMA)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"])      return @"iPad Air (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (CDMA)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini Retina (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini Retina (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (CDMA)";


    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

    return platform;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is good inside the application for using a different view in a Universal App like my post here: [Different view for devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048226/how-do-i-specify-fullscreen-background-images-in-xcode-so-redundant-images-aren/26869042#26869042)

If you want using a different Storyboard for a Different device you have to go in your `appDelegate.m`

First setting `MainIphone6` in your target.

and using this code under the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    result = CGSizeMake(result.width *scale, result.height *scale);

    if(result.height <= 1136){
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainIphone5" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
    }
    if(result.height <= 960){
            storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone4" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
            [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
        }
}
```

Then add your Storyboard iPad

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
    BOOL isIphone5()
    {
     if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)]) {
       CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
       CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
       result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);
       if(result.height == 1136){
       return YES;
       }
     }
     return NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't need to make decisions based on this information in your app.  If you find yourself wanting this information, chances are you should be making the decision based on some other criteria instead.

If you are dead set on doing this, see [Check iOS Simulator type and version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670898/check-ios-simulator-type-and-version/26680063#26680063) as well for how to do this in a way that the iOS Simulator will handle.